# Subsample a dataframe based on conditions in multiple columns a certain number of times in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that has an oversampling issue where one cohort was sampled far more than the other (In some cases it's by a factor of 4). I'm fairly certain I can resolve this by subsampling. For reference, the data was collected during a 'Trip' where multiple catch samples were collected during the day as well as night. What I'm trying to do is subset a total of 6 samples from each trip and specify that 3 are from night samples and the other three from day samples. The end goal is to have a dataframe that includes all the rows from 3 samples collected during the day and night from one trip and do this for each trip, ignoring the other samples. I have code that does something to this effect, but it only samples rows that meet those three criteria.
What I have so far:

```
Trip No.Sample DayNight TL_mm
T02       S01      Day    90
T02       S02      Day   285
T02       S03      Day    59
T02       S04    Night   110
T02       S05    Night   260
T02       S06    Night    56
T02       S07    Night   165
T02       S08    Night    78
T02       S09    Night    58
T03       S01      Day    91
T03       S02      Day    65
T03       S03      Day    73
T03       S04      Day    44
T03       S05      Day   226
T03       S05    Night    97
T03       S06    Night   250
T03       S07    Night    75
T03       S08    Night    80
T03       S09    Night    71
T03       S10    Night    76
```

What I want:

```
Trip No.Sample DayNight TL_mm
T02       S01      Day    90
T02       S02      Day   285
T02       S03      Day    59
T02       S04    Night   110
T02       S05    Night   260
T02       S06    Night    56
T03       S01      Day    91
T03       S02      Day    65
T03       S03      Day    73
T03       S05    Night    97
T03       S06    Night   250
T03       S07    Night    75
```

Here is what I have so far for code:

```
balanced_df<- data.frame(df %>%
                            group_by(Trip, No.Sample, DayNight) %>%
                            sample_n(size = 3) %>%
                            ungroup())
```

reprex data for usage:

```
structure(list(Trip = c("T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", 
"T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", 
"T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", 
"T02", "T02", "T02", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", 
"T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", 
"T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", 
"T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", 
"T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T03", "T04", "T04", "T04", 
"T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", 
"T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", 
"T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", "T04", 
"T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", 
"T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", "T05", 
"T05", "T05", "T05", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", 
"T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", 
"T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", 
"T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", "T06", 
"T06", "T06", "T06", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", 
"T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", 
"T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07", "T07"), No.Sample = c("S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04", 
"S04", "S04", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S06", "S06", "S06", "S07", 
"S07", "S07", "S08", "S08", "S08", "S09", "S09", "S09", "S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04", 
"S04", "S04", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S06", 
"S06", "S06", "S07", "S07", "S07", "S08", "S08", "S08", "S09", 
"S09", "S09", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S12", 
"S12", "S12", "S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", 
"S03", "S03", "S04", "S04", "S04", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S06", 
"S06", "S06", "S07", "S07", "S07", "S08", "S08", "S08", "S09", 
"S09", "S09", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", 
"S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04", "S04", "S04", "S05", 
"S05", "S05", "S06", "S06", "S06", "S07", "S07", "S07", "S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04", 
"S04", "S04", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S06", "S06", "S06", "S07", 
"S07", "S07", "S08", "S08", "S08", "S09", "S09", "S09", "S10", 
"S10", "S10", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S04", 
"S04", "S04", "S05", "S05", "S05", "S06", "S06", "S06", "S07", 
"S07", "S07"), DayNight = c("Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", 
"Day", "Day", "Day", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night"), TL_mm = c(60, 64, 70, 62, 80, 67, 65, 115, 70, 84, 
88, 88, 54, 248, 93, 96, 95, 95, 49, 215, 51, 190, 50, 86, 93, 
52, 49, 98, 62, 70, 45, 40, 50, 62, 80, 65, 55, 52, 77, 210, 
187, 235, 47, 80, 67, 62, 80, 88, 79, 83, 85, 68, 75, 82, 80, 
63, 71, 53, 97, 80, 84, 55, 89, 58, 60, 89, 52, 73, 63, 68, 55, 
267, 79, 86, 245, 56, 90, 46, 51, 97, 78, 85, 84, 75, 75, 222, 
88, 97, 72, 190, 105, 50, 65, 50, 260, 85, 89, 83, 81, 92, 90, 
85, 93, 95, 95, 61, 92, 65, 55, 90, 61, 77, 70, 84, 110, 100, 
65, 88, 91, 75, 70, 222, 86, 110, 45, 55, 90, 96, 93, 89, 93, 
80, 40, 100, 73, 94, 88, 69, 78, 100, 75, 45, 80, 65, 90, 49, 
53, 48, 95, 90, 80, 89, 102, 102, 89, 105, 71, 94, 37, 53, 102, 
94, 89, 76, 72, 36, 75, 84, 81, 100, 81, 64, 49, 76)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-174L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer first selects one measurement for each `No.Sample` on each trip, then picks up to 3 from the trip.:

```r
library(tidyverse)

glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 174
#> Columns: 4
#> $ Trip      <chr> "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02", "T02…
#> $ No.Sample <chr> "S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S03", "S03…
#> $ DayNight  <chr> "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day", "Day…
#> $ TL_mm     <dbl> 60, 64, 70, 62, 80, 67, 65, 115, 70, 84, 88, 88, 54, 248, 93…

df %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1, by = c(Trip, DayNight, No.Sample)) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 3, by = c(Trip, DayNight))
#>    Trip No.Sample DayNight TL_mm
#> 1   T02       S01      Day    64
#> 2   T02       S03      Day    65
#> 3   T02       S02      Day    80
#> 4   T02       S04    Night    84
#> 5   T02       S07    Night    51
#> 6   T02       S05    Night   248
#> 7   T03       S04      Day    77
#> 8   T03       S03      Day    80
#> 9   T03       S01      Day    70
#> 10  T03       S06    Night    88
#> 11  T03       S05    Night    80
#> 12  T03       S09    Night    63
#> 13  T04       S05      Day    97
#> 14  T04       S02      Day   267
#> 15  T04       S04      Day    56
#> 16  T04       S10    Night   260
#> 17  T04       S08    Night   190
#> 18  T04       S09    Night   105
#> 19  T05       S01      Day    89
#> 20  T05       S03      Day    93
#> 21  T05       S02      Day    92
#> 22  T05       S05    Night    55
#> 23  T05       S04    Night    61
#> 24  T05       S06    Night    77
#> 25  T06       S06      Day   100
#> 26  T06       S04      Day    93
#> 27  T06       S05      Day    89
#> 28  T06       S09    Night    45
#> 29  T06       S11    Night    95
#> 30  T06       S10    Night    49
#> 31  T07       S03      Day   102
#> 32  T07       S01      Day   105
#> 33  T07       S04      Day    76
#> 34  T07       S06    Night   100
#> 35  T07       S07    Night    49
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is very close, only caveat I've been struggling with is that a sample within a trip can only be used once. For example, in T03 all TL values are drawn from different samples, but in T04 two night TL values are drawn from sample 8. The biggest hurdle fro me has been specifying that once a sample has been drawn from within a trip, it cant be used again.

Comment: Hi @JacksonASwan, I think this is now addressed in the edited answer. First, select one sample per trip, then do the randomly sampling from the samples in the trip.